# Can JMS onMessage() reduce costs when implemented with Amazon AWS SQS?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, jms, amazon-sqs

I am creating an application where I want to use **Amazon AWS SQS**.
While reading about SQS, I got to know that amazon costs upon the number of request made to queue.

```
 1. Every Amazon SQS action counts as a request.
 2. API actions for sending, receiving, deleting, and changing visibility of messages from FIFO queues are charged at FIFO rates.  All other API requests are charged at standard rates.
enter code here
```

**Now i was looking upon things I can do to reduce costs.**

- Batch processing - (Lets leave it for a while)
- Long Polling - To reduce the cost of using Amazon SQS and to decrease the number of empty receives to an empty queue, enable long polling.
- With JMS, The onMessage method of the MessageListener interface is called when you receive a message. We don't have empty read request.

**My question**

> I know the first two points will reduce the cost. I am not sure about
>   the third one. Can anyone elaborate if implementing listener will
>   reduce or increase or it is same as that of short or long polling.

Let me know in case you need more details.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's more about the economics of SQS billing than an actual question about programming.

Comment: Well, i am going to implement based on billing. If listener implementation is costly, i will implement other way. You should not close this as this is important for developers who are not rich.

Comment: The fact remains that this question is more about SQS billing practices than programming and therefore doesn't really belong on Stack Overflow.

Comment: then can you please tell me where should i divert these types of questions ?

Comment: It seems like dealing with Amazon directly would make sense given that they are the authority on their own billing practices. They should be able to tell you how certain API calls translate into billable transactions.

Comment: To address the core if your issue and not the costs - SQS only works by polling.  If you look at [some of the code](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sqs-java-messaging-lib/blob/master/src/main/java/com/amazon/sqs/javamessaging/SQSMessageConsumerPrefetch.java) it's just a thread polling SQS and sending a message via JMS.  So even if your `onMessage` isn't getting called SQS is still being polled.

Comment: For what it's worth, even the [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/amazon-web-services/info) for `amazon-web-services` says, "ONLY QUESTIONS ABOUT PROGRAMMING ARE ON-TOPIC."